# Marquee Text in C# without Timer

Tags: c#, text

I want to marquee text in C# Windows application. There are some project like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24587/Easy-to-Use-Marquee-Control-for-Windows-Form-with) in Code project, but They don't support Left To Right Moving. And also the marque text will change in run time. 
I used timer for this purpose, but it dosent have good Moving. It pause for 0.1 sec every second. Bcz the computer dosent have good config and also I used a lot of timer in my project. Any suggest?

```
private void timerRollText_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Enabled)
        {
            if (RollTextContent.Count == 0 || RollTextContent == null)
                return;

            if (strRollTextContent != strRollTextTemp)
            {
                strRollTextTemp = strRollTextContent;

                labelRollTextContent.Text = strRollTextContent;
                XPos = 0 - labelRollTextContent.Size.Width;
                RightToLeft = false;
            }


            if (!RightToLeft)
            {
                labelRollTextContent.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(XPos, labelRollTextContent.Location.Y);
                XPos += 1;

                if (XPos > (this.Width + 20))
                {
                    XPos = 0 - labelRollTextContent.Size.Width;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Marquee text? You'd better invest in some protection, I see hordes of angry users coming at you with pitchforks in my crystal ball.

Comment: Render to a bitmap, move the bitmap? Still, Cody's right. Say no to marquee text.

Comment: Better get already built control for that, don't re-invent the wheel, here is a couple of good controls providers that I've tried before. [Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

Comment: Can you suggest me some good controls ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all using marque will eat your resources, so if possible avoid it.

In either case to make marque you will end up using Timer by your self or inbuilt systems.

But for that moving delay you have to consider the time Time Interval of Timer control. So if you have Interval which is small then it will move smoothly.

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Eat his resources?  Eat his user base.

Comment: The time interval of my timer is 1.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve marque effect by removing a character and inserting it at required place.(No need to move label or picture). But here string should be appended with spaces to get marque of required length.

**Example**

Let "**abcde...................**" is the required text (here '.' is appended instead of space for simplicity)

For moving **right-to-left** delete first character(here 'a') and append this to remaining string

```
MarqueLabel.Text = MarqueLabel.Text.Substring(1) + MarqueLabel.Text.First();
```

"abcde..................."
"bcde...................a"
"cde...................ab"
For moving **left-to-right** delete last character(here '.') and insert at starting position.

```
MarqueLabel.Text = MarqueLabel.Text.Last() + MarqueLabel.Text.Remove(MarqueLabel.Text.Length - 1);
```

"abcde..................."
".abcde.................."
"..abcde................."

So here above code lines can be repeated within a **thread** or a **timer**, incase of threads we have to use `Thread.Sleep()` or `Task.Delay()` for delay. You can also create your own UserControl.

Following is the sample code i have written using asynchronous method.

```
bool LeftToRight = false;
int delay = 100; // Milliseconds
ManualResetEvent PauseUnpauseMarque = new ManualResetEvent(true);
private async void StartMarque()
{           
    while (true)  //Infinite loop(here we can use a global constant for breaking)
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>PauseUnpauseMarque.WaitOne());
        if (LeftToRight)
            MarqueLabel.Text = MarqueLabel.Text.Last() + MarqueLabel.Text.Remove(MarqueLabel.Text.Length - 1);
        else                
            MarqueLabel.Text = MarqueLabel.Text.Substring(1) + MarqueLabel.Text.First(); 
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

Here `MarqueLabel` is a Label control which contains required text(Padded with spaces).

**Starting Marque**

```
StartMarque();
```

**Pause Marque**

```
PauseUnpauseMarque.Reset();
```

**Resume Marque**

```
PauseUnpauseMarque.Set();
```

**Additional Information**
Here you can use `Task marqueTask = Task.Run(() => StartMarque());` so that you can control(destroy,pause,etc.,) task with `marqueTask`
(or)
You can use a global variable which can be checked in the `while` loop for breaking the loop

```
bool StopMarque = false;
private async void StartMarque()
{           
    while (!StopMarque)
    {
       .............
       .............
    }
}
```

set `StopMarque=true` for breaking loop.

Here i used asynchronous method instead of this you can also try with threads.